# R arules: Signify Duplicate itemsets

Tags: r, arules

I am qualitatively coding a dataset based on theme.  Each observation is allowed two themes, therefore I have two columns with the same variable list.  When I run arules, it see "v1=alpha; v2=beta" as different item than "v1=beta;v2=alpha."  As below,

| V1        | V2   |

| -------- | ----- |

| ALPHA   | BETA   |

| BETA  | ALPHA   |

Here's my code:

```
  pr_itemset<-apriori(
     pr_trans,parameter=list(
     target="frequent",support=.001,minlen=2,maxlen=4))
```

Comment: So My question is if there is a way for it to recognize these as the same

Answer (score 0):

These two rows are different. If you actually want the items to be ALPHA and BETA without the V1 and V2 because each row represents a set of items then you should start with a list of sets (represented as character vectors). The code would look like this:

```
library("arules")
mysets <- list(
   c('ALPHA', 'BETA'),
   c('BETA', 'ALPHA')
   )
trans <- transactions(mysets)

inspect(trans)
    items        
[1] {ALPHA, BETA}
[2] {ALPHA, BETA}

identical(trans[1], trans[2])
[1] TRUE
```